# APTANA Formatting Javascript code with PHP statement

Tags: javascript, php, aptana, formatter

Aptana Studio formatter doesn't work properly when I mix PHP and JavaScript in my .js file.

My code is:

```
{
alert("<?php echo $LANG[$iPage]["DureeNotPage"] ?>");
```

The formatter puts a new line before and after the `<?php ... ?>` part:

```
{
alert("
<?php echo $LANG[$iPage]["DureeNotPage"] ?>
");
```

I tried default prodile, jQuery javascript style guide and Google javascript style guide but this keeps happening.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: try this alert("<?php echo $LANG[$iPage]["DureeNotPage"] ?>");

Comment: I do that but when I press Ctrl + Shift + F it's insert a new line before and after "php" tag